# ansible jinja filter

Tags: filter, ansible, jinja2

Имеются хосты с именами xyz01 xyz01 xyz03 xyz04. Как при помощи jinja шаблона и фильтров получить только числа?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56878092/5430535 не оно?